# iOS app crashing in release mode, works in debug mode

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Recently my app started breaking if I create the .ipa file for AppStore release. It works fine if I run the same code in emulator or if I run it on my iPhone from xcode, but once I create the release package it crashes while opening a particular view controller.

I went through few of the posts on Stackoverflow where people had similar problems and tried following things:

- Setting `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";` for release mode
- Setting `GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;` for release mode
- Commenting out some of the UI components which were added recently

Following is the log I got from the device:

```
Incident Identifier: 4F30BFF1-71DC-4542-A330-F3786B3302A8
CrashReporter Key:   f6fcec71c8263640bd75a0d18937c323d8a95b43
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             Dummy [633]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/370692A3-C880-4008-8C70-641801FB894A/Dummy.app/Dummy
Identifier:          com.example.Dummy
Version:             1.0.71 (1.0.71)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.example.Dummy [741]


Date/Time:           2017-10-09 18:08:28.2604 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-10-09 18:07:45.3034 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100518448
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100518448 0x1003c0000 + 1410120
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100518448 0x1003c0000 + 1410120
2   Dummy                           0x00000001000e2e14 0x10003c000 + 683540
3   Dummy                           0x00000001000e351c 0x10003c000 + 685340
4   UIKit                           0x000000018b5d3ec0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1036
5   UIKit                           0x000000018b68bff0 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
6   UIKit                           0x000000018b68bec8 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 416
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b68b1f8 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 144
8   UIKit                           0x000000018b68ac2c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 856
9   UIKit                           0x000000018b68a7e0 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 64
10  UIKit                           0x000000018b68a744 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
11  UIKit                           0x000000018b5d107c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1200
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001887c1274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001887b5de8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001887b5ca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
15  QuartzCore                      0x000000018873134c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
16  QuartzCore                      0x00000001887583ac CA::Transaction::commit() + 504
17  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188758e78 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001854509a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018544e630 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018544ea7c __CFRunLoopRun + 956
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018537eda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
22  GraphicsServices                0x0000000186de8074 GSEventRunModal + 100
23  UIKit                           0x000000018b639058 UIApplicationMain + 208
24  Dummy                           0x0000000100105f34 0x10003c000 + 827188
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018438d59c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562ca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185450e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018544eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018537eda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x0000000185e98d74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185eb9b44 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018bfc36a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185f962d8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456568c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456559c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f09c mach_msg + 72
2   Dummy                           0x000000010012fcf4 0x10003c000 + 998644
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456568c _pthread_body + 240
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456559c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185450e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018544eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018537eda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000185b8adf4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185f962d8 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456568c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456559c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018447f09c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185450e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018544eae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018537eda4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   AVFAudio                        0x000000019f6c2540 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AVFAudio                        0x000000019f6e8814 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456568c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018456559c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018449da88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001845631a4 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562cac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562ca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018449da88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001845631a4 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562cac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184562ca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000100d20b80   x1: 0x00000001742ea580   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x00000001844e32c0
    x4: 0x00000000ffb80038   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0048000004210103   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001742e9980   x9: 0x00000001742e9980  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
   x12: 0x0000010000000100  x13: 0x206e6120676e6970  x14: 0x6c616e6f6974704f  x15: 0x000a65756c617620
   x16: 0x00000001844d3a1c  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000002  x21: 0x0000000000000039  x22: 0x000000010022ac40  x23: 0x0000000000000002
   x24: 0x000000000000000b  x25: 0x0000000100231dc8  x26: 0x0000000171a68480  x27: 0x00000001aa543000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016fdc0ee0   lr: 0x0000000100518448
    sp: 0x000000016fdc0ea0   pc: 0x0000000100518448 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

I am using Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b), Swift3. Please let me know if someone had similar issue before, or any guesses to fix this problem!

Thanks!

Comment: You need to symbolicate frames 2 and 3 to understand the crash report.

Comment: you are using something that is a nil there, try to move it to viewDidAppear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to symbolicate crash exactly where it is crashing from frames 2 and 3.

You can symbolicate crash like below:

Based on this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid%20/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATEWITHXCODE)

[image]

In your case you have to call as below :

```
atos -arch arm64 -o <PATH TO Dummy.app.dSYM>/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Dummy -l 0x10003c000 0x00000001000e2e14
```

**`Dummy.app.dSYM`** is located in

1. right click on `Dummy.xcarchive` and then `Show Package Contents`.
2. In that `dSYMs` folder is there
3. `Dummy.app.dSYM` is located in the `dSYMs` folder
4. Copy `Dummy.app.dSYM` to somewhere to your local system.
5. `<PATH TO Dummy.app.dSYM>` will be the path of the `Dummy.app.dSYM` in your local system

Comment: Thanks, @Vini for detailed description of debugging, it did give me some understandable output for above-asked question, but after I changed my code and rebuilt the project, I am still having the same problem except that now symbolicating crash gives something like `0xfff58b04 (in Dummy)`, any ideas how to debug it further?

Comment: You have to debug same as above by changing the load address

Comment: I am taking the new crash logs and .dSYM files to debug, and again passing Address (to symbolicate) and Load Address from the new crash logs, is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Ok, so I used symbolicatecrash tool as described [here](https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/) and could symbolicate the crash logs and found the problem! Thanks @Vini, Kerni, Lu_ for pointing out where to start from!