# iOS crash log help needed about webkit

Tags: ios, crash, webkit

this is a iOS cash log ,i can't find where the crash so need to help.
I think the crash maybe case by third part but the log not show where 
crash.

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8nkU.png)

[image: log]

thanks very much.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673950/ios-app-crashing-in-release-mode-works-in-debug-mode/46676644#46676644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some advices:

1. Desymbolicate your logs. 
   [Read here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) (It may not be so useful here as its in webkit).
2. Try NSZombie option enabled with Xcode - or even use the instruments option
3. Use something like (or exactly) Crashlytics by Fabric, there are many tools for the job but this is free and works well. It requires to be built in but makes the process MUCH easier as you get logs.

Based solely on the log alone, all I can say is it's possibly a reference issue, either within the web view itself or because the web view was cleaned up and still firing.